# How to generate an "App" access token from .Net Desktop application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

According to 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

an App access token can be generated by using this Graph API call
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials

When I issue through a browser control in a .Net app I get this URL returned along with a web page prompting me to log in

https://www.facebook.com/oauth/accesstoken?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials

After I log in, I get three responses, one after the other in the web control as follows :

https://www.facebook.com/ai.php?aed=<1496 digit hash>
https://www.facebook.com/ai.php?aed=<1411 digit hash>
https://www.facebook.com/oauth/accesstoken?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials

Nowhere there is an &access_token parameter.

How do I generate an App access token. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You can use 'APP_ID+"|"+APP_SECRET' as an App Access token if it's lifetime doesn't bother you.

Comment: Thank you. But what is its lifetime ?  I would want to to last indefinitely if possible.

Comment: I have tried the suggested method with the following code 
string accesstoken = m_AppId & "|" & m_AppSecret                        Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accesstoken);
                        Facebook.JsonObject fbMe = (Facebook.JsonObject)fb.Get("me");   and the second line throws an exception stating OAuth Exception #2500  An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."   What am I doing wrong here ?